# Spock with Spring Boot and Camel: Zero interactions with detached mock

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spock, spring-boot-test, spring-camel

I am having some issues with testing my camel context with spring boot.

I am using spring boot 1.5.6, spock 1.1-groovy-2.4, camel 2.19.2, and camel-spring-boot-starter 2.19.2.

I am using a spock mock, and I'm using the `DetachedMockFactory` in a `@TestConfiguration` class.  All of my beans use constructor injection.  I am injecting a mocked `@Repository` into one of the processor `@Component`s, and I am also injecting it into my test class to define interactions.

I have my test annotated with `@SpringBootTest` with the classes list including all `Processor` implementations, and all `RouteBuilder` extensions.  I also have an '@Import' with my `TestConfiguration` class.  I am even using constructor injection for this repository bean in my test!

But it seems that the mock that is injected into the test class is not the one that is in use. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?  I have tried `@DirtiesContext` to reload the context both before and after each test, but that did not help.

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/758 my guess is that your mock is also wrapped in a proxy. If that is not the case you'll have to create a MCVE and share it.

Comment: Leonard, thank you for the information. This helped me, but in a slightly different way than how you described. The mock was proxied by cglib, so instead of using AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(proxy), I used AopUtils.isCglibProxy(proxy). Depending on the situation, others might need to use AopUtils.isAopProxy(proxy).

Thank you for the suggestion!  You should post this as an answer so that I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with DetachedMocks not behaving correctly, e.g., appearing to be the same instance, are usually caused by some framework wrapping them in proxies. For example this can be caused by `@Transactional` annotation in Spring, which creates a proxy to facilitate jdbc-session management. See also issue [#758](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/758)

For spring you can use the methods of `AopUtils` ([jdoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils.html)). The simple way is to use `AopUtils.isAopProxy` to check if it is proxied by spring an then unwrap it.

```
public static <T> T getTargetObject(Object proxy) throws Exception {
    if (AopUtils.isAopProxy(proxy)) {
        return (T) ((Advised) proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget();
    } else {
        return (T) proxy;
    }
}
```

And in a Test

```
def "sample service test"() {
    given:
    def sampleRepositryMock = getTargetObject(sampleRepositry)
    when:
    sampleService.doSomething()   // simply invoke sampleRepositry.doSomething() in it
    then:
    1 * sampleRepositryMock.doSomething() 
    0 * _                   
}
```

---

Edit: Since Spock 1.2 there is an extension to automatically unwrap injected beans `@UnwrapAopProxy`.

```
@Inject
@UnwrapAopProxy
SampleRepositry sampleRepositryMock
```

Comment: I think that, for Spring, you mean isCglibProxy(), but close enough!  Thanks again!

Comment: @SteveStorck both are for Spring, `isAopProxy()` is detecting both jdkproxy and cglib proxies as you can see in the linked Javadoc.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll make the changes to my code to use that, then.  Thanks again for the awesome advice.

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes up with the same problem.

Spock added additional `@UnwrapAopProxy` that will do the job for you instead of the util method mentioned above. You can also drop the `DetachedMockFactory`

```
@SpringSpy
@UnwrapAopProxy
Service service
```